# What is the mysqld_safe command for Windows-based installations?

Tags: windows, mariadb

I need to run the `mysqld_safe` command in a MariaDB installation, but I cannot find it inside the `\bin` folder...

Answer (score 0):

`mysqld_safe` is a unix script so won't exist on the Windows installs.

There will be `mariadbd.exe`, or `mysqld.exe` on pre 10.5 versions. MariaDB should exist as a service in the Windows installation, so recommend looking there more how to start it.